# Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array error while inserting tags in form

Tags: php, pivot, relationship, laravel-routing

I am using tags in the form in an array.while inserting it shows error as :
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array.

My code:

**view page**

```
<div class="form-group">
           <label>TAGS</label><br>
           {!! Form::select('tags[]',$tags,null,['id'=>'tag_id','class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 $newPortfolio = $portfolio->create(
        array(
            "first_name" => $request->input('first_name'),

        ));

    $tags = $request->input('tags');

    $newPortfolio->tags()->attach($tags);
```

}
 i am using many to many relationship and used pivot table..
any solution why is this problem ocuring ???